# Gradient descent on a convex quadratic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a quadratic equation $f(w) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}w^{T}Aw - b^{T}w$

$A$ is a symmetric matrix and it can be eigendecomposed into $Q\mathbf{\Lambda}Q^{T}$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix

I want to perform gradient descent and I have the equation:

$w^{k+1} = w^{k} - \alpha\nabla f(w) = w^k - \alpha(Aw^k - b)$

I want to substitute $x^k = Q^{T}(w^k - w^*)$ where $w^*$ is the optimal solution and produce $x^{k+1} = x^{k} - \alpha\Lambda x^{k}$

Here is my process:

$w^{k+1} = w^k - \alpha(Aw^k - b) \Leftrightarrow w^{k+1} - w^* = (w^k - w^*) - \alpha(Aw^k - b) \\
\Leftrightarrow Q^T(w^{k+1} - w^*) = Q^T(w^k - w^*) - \alpha Q^T(Aw^k - b) \\
\Leftrightarrow x^{k+1} = x^{k} - \alpha(Q^TQ\Lambda Q^T(w^k - w^* + w^*) - b) \Leftrightarrow x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha(\Lambda x^k + \Lambda Q^Tw^* - b) \\
\Leftrightarrow x^{k+1} = x^{k} - \alpha(\Lambda x^k + \Lambda Q^T(A^{-1}b) - b) = x^k - \alpha\Lambda x^k - \alpha(Q^Tb - b)$

Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, on your third line, when adding and subtracting a $w^{\ast}$, you should've included $b$ inside the parenthesis:

$
\begin{align}
x^{k+1} &= x^{k} - \alpha(Q^{T}(Q\Lambda Q^{T})(w^{k} - w^{\ast} + w^{\ast}) - b) \\
&= x^{k} - \alpha \Lambda Q^{T} (w^{k} - w^{\ast} + w^{\ast}) + \alpha Q^{T} b \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
$

Second, you only mentioned $A$ is symmetric, but that doesn't necessarily mean you can take its inverse on the last line. You would need $A$ to be, for example, positive definite for that step to make sense.

If this is a homework question, I recommend also explaining why $w^{\ast} = A^{-1}b$ provided that $A$ is invertible. Should take you no more than a sentence or two.